# Metadata version mismatch for module node_modules/ng2-emoji/ng2-emoji.d.ts, found version 3, expected 1

Tags: android, ios, npm, ionic2

Metadata version mismatch for module 
            node_modules/ng2-emoji/ng2-emoji.d.ts, found version 3, expected 1

ionic **build android --release --prod**

error log

```
[17:18:28]  build prod failed: Metadata version mismatch for module 
        D:/projects/siilo/node_modules/ng2-emoji/ng2-emoji.d.ts, found version 3, expected 1 
[17:18:28]  ionic-app-script task: "build" 
[17:18:28]  Error: Metadata version mismatch for module D:/projects/siilo/node_modules/ng2-emoji/ng2-emoji.d.ts, found 
        version 3, expected 1 
Error: Metadata version mismatch for module D:/projects/siilo/node_modules/ng2-emoji/ng2-emoji.d.ts, found version 3, expected
1
at StaticReflector.getModuleMetadata (D:\projects\siilo\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\static_reflector.js:500:23)
at D:\projects\siilo\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\codegen.js:122:46
at Array.forEach (native)
at extractProgramSymbols (D:\projects\siilo\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\codegen.js:120:10)
at CodeGenerator.codegen (D:\projects\siilo\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\codegen.js:57:29)
at D:\projects\siilo\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:51:34
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ionic-hello-world@ ionic:build: `ionic-app-scripts build "--release" "--prod"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ionic-hello-world@ ionic:build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ikrok-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-06-01T14_18_28_386Z-debug.log
```

ionic info:

```
cordova CLI: 7.0.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.0.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.10.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Comment: This looks like an Angular version dependency problem. I suspect you are on Angular 3. But I can see that ng2-emoji [requires](https://github.com/AhsanAyaz/ng2-emoji/blob/677a77f6a35b15e807d9a0aa37f261915f03a14f/package.json#L26) Angular 4. I posted a general solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534610/error-in-metadata-version-mismatch-for-module-x-found-version-4-expected-3-res/47534611#47534611